# Solving type error issue with python list

Tags: python

I am trying to graph the output of serial and parallel execution times but keep getting

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'.

How do i divide contents of the list so so i don't get this error

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>        49 
>        50     # Compute the ratio of these times
>   ---> 51     ratio.append(serialTime/parallelTime)
>        52 
>        53
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sleep for t seconds
def burnTime(t):
    time.sleep(t)

# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 16 # The number of jobs
    P = 4  # The number of processes

    # A thread pool of P processes
    pool = mp.Pool(P)

  # Use a variety of wait times
    ratio = []
    wait_time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    #serial results    
    print("Serial Execution Times")
    for _ in range(N):
        start_time = time.time()
        serialTime = [burnTime(t) for t in wait_time]
        print("---- {} seconds ---- ".format(time.time() - start_time))


    print("\n")

    #parallel results
    print("Parallel Execution Times")
    for _ in range(N):
        start_time = time.time()
        parallelTime = pool.map(burnTime, wait_time)
        print("---- {} seconds ---- ".format(time.time() - start_time))



    for t in wait_time:
          pass
    # Compute jobs serially and in parallel
    # Use time.time() to compute the elapsed time for each
       # serialTime = 1
        #parallelTime = 1



    # Compute the ratio of these times
    ratio.append(serialTime/parallelTime)


    # Plot the results
    plt.plot(wait_time, ratio, '-ob')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.xlabel('Wait Time (sec)')
    plt.ylabel('Serial Time (sec) / Parallel Time (sec)')
    plt.title('Speedup versus function time')
    plt.show()

Output of SerialTime
---- 6.604194641113281e-05 seconds ---- 
---- 1.9073486328125e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 9.5367431640625e-07 seconds ---- 
---- 2.1457672119140625e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 2.1457672119140625e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 1.9073486328125e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 9.5367431640625e-07 seconds ---- 
---- 2.1457672119140625e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 1.9073486328125e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 9.5367431640625e-07 seconds ---- 
---- 1.1920928955078125e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 2.1457672119140625e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 1.9073486328125e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 1.1920928955078125e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 2.1457672119140625e-06 seconds ---- 
---- 1.9073486328125e-06 seconds ---- 

output of ParalleTime
---- 12.006800889968872 seconds ---- 
---- 12.004575967788696 seconds ---- 
---- 12.00544810295105 seconds ---- 
---- 12.006248950958252 seconds ---- 
---- 12.003881216049194 seconds ---- 
---- 12.005573749542236 seconds ---- 
---- 12.003982067108154 seconds ---- 
---- 12.003642082214355 seconds ---- 
---- 12.004355192184448 seconds ---- 
---- 12.00377106666565 seconds ---- 
---- 12.003960132598877 seconds ---- 
---- 12.004532098770142 seconds ---- 
---- 12.003446578979492 seconds ---- 
---- 12.003416776657104 seconds ---- 
---- 12.004649877548218 seconds ---- 
---- 12.004476070404053 seconds ----
```

Comment: why are dividing a list by another list, what exactly do you want to happen in `ratio.append(serialTime/parallelTime)`

Comment: I want to divide serial execution times by parallel execution times so I can graph them against wait times. I'm sure there is a better approach but I am stuck

Comment: can you check my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than dividing two lists, you can do the following to get the ratio of two lists:

```
ratio.append([x / y for x, y in zip(serialTime, parallelTime)])
```

Comment: I get a different error now - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'NoneType'

Comment: can you share the items inside the list `serialTime` and `parallelTime`

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: can you just print something like this `print(serialTime)` and `print(parallelTime)`

Comment: that won't print out the execution time

Comment: what is this line doing `serialTime = [burnTime, _ in range(N), wait_time]`

Comment: That line is incorrect so I changed it to  serialTime = [burnTime(t) for t in wait_time]. All it is doing is iterating through wait_time and applying the function burnTime.

Comment: Actually the output of `print(serialTime)` is a list of `None's`, because the function `burnTime` is not returning anything so by default the function returns `None`. What I would like to suggest is you can append `time.time() - start_time)` for `serialTime`.

Answer (score 0):

divide serial execution times by parallel execution times

```
result = list(map(lambda x: x[0]/x[1], zip(serialTime, parallelTime)))
```

btw, I have tried your code and got:

```
>>> serialTime
[<function burnTime at 0x103221e18>, True, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> parallelTime
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

check it